# The integrals of $L^1$ functions can be made small by integrating over a small set.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f \in L^1 (\mathbf{R})$. Prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ so that $\int_A |f| \leq \epsilon$ whenever $A$ is a measurable set with $m(A) \leq \delta$.

My attempt thus far.
Let $\epsilon > 0$. 
Set $f_n = 1_{|x| \leq n}|f| $ so that $f_n$ is a vertical truncation with $f_n \to |f|$ and $\int_{R} f_n \to \int_{R} |f|$, i.e., there exists a natural $N$ such that $n \geq N \implies \epsilon \geq \int_R |f| - 1_{|x|\leq n} |f| =\int_R |f|(1_R - 1_{|x| \leq n}) = \int_{(-\infty, n) \cup (n, \infty)} |f|$.

I feel like I have taken the wrong approach since $(-\infty, n) \cup (n, \infty)$ is a set of infinite measure for all $n$. Where did I go wrong, and what is a better way to prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that for every integrable function $f$, there is a simple function $\phi$ such that $\int_E|f - \phi| < \epsilon/2$.  Recall also that, writing $\phi = \sum \alpha_i\chi_{A_i}$ (the canonical form), $\int_E\phi = \sum\alpha_im(E\cap A_i) \le m(E)\sum\alpha_i$.  Choose $\delta < \epsilon/(2\sum\alpha_i)$.  If $\phi$ is negative for some values, then write $\int_E|\phi| = \sum|\alpha_i|m(E\cap A_i)$.  Then
\begin{equation}
\big|\int_E f\big| \le \int_E|f - \phi| + \int_E|\phi| < \epsilon
\end{equation}
which follows by from the triangle inequality.  Hence, we have found such our desired restriction on measurable sets.